# Debian and Windows

Tags: windows, debian

For my school project we have been asked to talk about the similarities between Linux and Windows, and to relate some of the tasks we have done in school with Windows (both GUI and CL). Does anyone know anything that you can do on either Windows (GUI and CL) and on Debian CL? Also, are there any advantages for either one over the other, such as ease-of-use, or more complex things such as its being easier to create new users and assign them to groups?

I have been asked to get primary research, so I’m not asking you to write a project for me, just to mention some things that you think are easier on either one.

Comment: How do you think your teacher will feel if he sees us writing your project for you? You need to learn how to do your own research.

Comment: no, i have been asked to crowd source research so i can have some primary research from other people, as well as secondary sources

Comment: We don't do crowd sourcing.

Answer (score 1):

I am on cloud nine to hear that in some schools people learn not only **Microsoft Office**, **Pascal** and **Basic**.

I suggest that you first of all install [**VirtualBox**](https://www.virtualbox.org/). It is a good program to investigate and work with a rich set of operating systems, including even exotic ones like **OS/4** or **Haiku**. Here you can download **.iso** installation image of [**Debian**](https://www.debian.org/distrib/) ([installation guide](http://www.brianlinkletter.com/installing-debian-linux-in-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine/)). Raw **Debian** is one of the best choices to investigate **Linux**. In **Linux** or any other **Unix-like** OS (like **Solaris**, **FreeBSD** etc.), you should use `man command` or `command --help` for all what you need to use.

There's also a **Linux**-like environment for **Windows**, called [**Cygwin**](https://www.cygwin.com/).

There are also some websites which are created to provide information about operating systems, for example, [**OSDev**](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page).

Enjoy!

By the way, comparing **Windows** and **Unix** command lines is not a better idea than comparing syntaxes of **Basic** and **Perl**.